# How to turn one server into many servers? (Virtualization/VMWare)

Tags: tcp, vmware, virtualization

I'm hoping for a high level discussion of this problem I know is quickly approaching my application.

I have a server that binds on a specific port and manages TCP Sockets from my clients. I know that it is common practice to use VMWare to virtualize servers and run multiple servers at once.

**How can a single server design be changed to support multiple servers?**

Multiple servers can't bind to the same port. If I had to guess I would say a proxy server binds to the port and then sends connections off to the other servers to be handled as if it was still a single server application.

I'm wondering what options there are and what are the common practices for solving this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your question may have better answers on a admin based forum, voting to move

Comment: An admin based forum being what?

Comment: The metastack has a few forums devoted to specialist subjects - this is for programming questions mostly - there is one dedicated to server admin stuff/VM's and all that - your question will be automatically moved if my fellows agree with my vote on your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each VMWare machine is essentially a standalone PC, as far as the OS running inside a VM is concerned.  Like on a real PC, a server can bind to the same port on different IPs, and each running VM can have its own IP on the virtualized network.  VMWare has a built-in DHCP router that manages the IPs and network traffic of its running VMs.  Each VM can have its own real independant IP on the Host machine's actual network, or they can share the Host's IP via VMWare's built-in router.  The OS in each VM doesn't know the difference.  Go ahead and bind your server to the same port on each running VM, it will work fine.  VMWare will handle the packet routing as needed.

Comment: Amazing! I assumed binding to a port was a hardware constraint. I think I need to read some manuals on VMWare. It appears to be more powerful than I had anticipated.

Comment: Do not forget the hardware limitations of the host NIC - if its a 10Mb NIC then that gets shared amongst the guests

Comment: Port binding is not handled by hardware, it is handled by the OS. The hardware receives a network packet and gives it to the OS, which matches it to a bound network adapter for applications to consume. When sending data, an application gives its data to a network adapter, which looks at its bindings and gives the relevant info to the OS, which give the packet to the hardware to transmit. In the case of a VM, the "hardware" is VMWare, which passes the data to/from the Host's hardware as needed.